# Printing In Safari Resulting In Blank Pages

Tags: javascript, safari

So I have some code that will take a blob and attempt to print it. This works fine the first time you click print in Safari. If you cancel the printing prompt, subsequent requests to print will show a white screen with infinite pages.

I was wondering if this is a core issue with safari, as this happens printing the document directly through JavaScript. Or if there's something I'm missing.

This only happens if you cancel a print. If you continue and finish printing, everything will work fine again until you click cancel on a print job initiated by JavaScript.

```js
  let printPdf = function (b64) {
    const b64toBlob = (b64Data, contentType = '', sliceSize = 512) => {
      const byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
      const byteArrays = [];
      for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
          const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize),
              byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
          for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
              byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
          }
          const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
  
          byteArrays.push(byteArray);
      }
      const blob = new Blob(byteArrays, { type: contentType });
      return blob;
    }

    const contentType = "application/pdf",
    blob = b64toBlob(b64, contentType),
    blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    console.dir('new print');
    var iframe = null;

    iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);

    iframe.style.display = 'none';
    iframe.onload = function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        iframe.focus();
        iframe.contentWindow.print();
      }, 500);
    };
  
    iframe.src = blobUrl;
  }
```

[Here's a screenshot of the infinite printing window.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fb0wK.png)